# 10kV high voltage switch using mosfet stack

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to make a pulse generator for a 10kV power supply, few mA.

Surprisingly, I could not find any standard design of HV switch using mosfet (Sic or not) stacks.

Could someone give me some guidelines?

Ideally I would like to reach faster than 100ns commutation and use only standard components.

Comment: Not an answer, but I've tried to do this and it is quite difficult and subtle to get right. You could look up sic jfet cascodes.

Comment: I agree, it is quite complicated to get a good voltage distribution across all MOSFETs during turn-on and turn-off. Furthermore 10 kV is high voltage and one needs to be extremely careful with such voltage levels, which can be deadly.

Comment: This paper MAY be of use. Or not :-) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/55e1/b9d916cc8282e52ba3c4414aab6d640d653c.pdf

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is not trivial. that being said you might be able to find a couple kilovolt designs for lasers, but I know you can find a few kilovolt mosfets so those designs might actually not be helpful in these cases...

Comment: faster than 100ns commutation with 10 kV and standard components is very ambigious

Comment: Standard by package means. I would like to avoid expensive modules.

Comment: @Jeffbeck I think you're better off using a hydrogen thyratron for high voltage, high speed switching than using MOSFETs

Answer (score 2):

This is quite difficult to achieve and in some sense still a topic of research, there is not a surefire way to stack MOSFETs in series and assure the voltage will be divided evenly at all times during operation.

You gotta think about it like this, whoever has the highest impedance will have the most voltage, if it is too high it will break and then the next highest impedance will get the highest voltage and they will get damaged in cascade. I won't even start talking about ensuring they all operate synchronously, specially with the commutation speed you are asking for.

Another issue is how you isolate the gate circuit for each, you could use inverters, transformers and DC/DC converters to isolate each gate driver and then use fiber optics or something alike to deliver the trigger to each MOSFET at different voltage levels... each has to  be able to isolate your maximum voltage so you need 10 gate circuits that can isolate 10kV for each MOSFET. You could argue that if you had 10, you could make 10 circuits that can work at floating 1kV... but as I said before it is very hard to guarantee that condition.

also define standard... if it is that voltage and current there are single devices that can handle it.

https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/854/product/0/high_voltage_sic_power_modules_for_10_25_kv_applications.pdf

this is not advertisement for that company, just to show you that those things exist, if that is within your range of standard components I think it is better to go for that.

I think your best bet is a single expensive SiC IGBT/MOSFET(module) to handle this, making a stack requires a lot of knowledge and experimentation to get it to work.

High voltage is highly dangerous... so be careful.

Comment: yes that is my conclusion. Again, I got surprised about it. thanks.